# JavaFx: Access an object from Event handler

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I want to make a program in JavaFX that contains a button which, when clicked, a circle gets created and added to an ArrayList of shapes. The following is my code:

```
createCircleBtn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            Circle circle1 = new Circle();
            shapes.add(circle1);
            circle1.setCenterX(event.getX());
            circle1.setCenterY(event.getY());
            circle1.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
         // doesn't work because "circle1" must be declared final (constant) 
                    circle1.setCenterX(event.getX());
                    // "this" doesn't refer to "circle1"
                    this.setCenterY(event.getY());
                }
            });
            mainPane.getChildren().add(circle1);
        }
    });
```

My question is - How can I access "circle1" from inside handle method?
In JavaScript we use `e.currentTarget`.

I'm unable to declare "circle1" final because I will need to change it afterwards.

Comment: You define your `Circle` instance OUTSIDE of `handle` method and `EventHandler` scope.

Comment: @BranislavLazic  My Circle instance is defined OUTSIDE of handle method if you meant the second handle method , and i can't declare outside the first handle method because the circle must be created after clicking the button.

Comment: Can't you just declare it to be `final`? I.e. `final Circle circle1 = new Circle();`?

Comment: "i can't declare "circle1" final because i will need to change it." **final does not mean immutable**. it just means you can not re-assign it.

Comment: ok , thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere in the code you show do you reassign `circle1`, so you can just declare it as `final`:

```
createCircleBtn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            final Circle circle1 = new Circle();
            shapes.add(circle1);
            circle1.setCenterX(event.getX());
            circle1.setCenterY(event.getY());
            circle1.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    circle1.setCenterX(event.getX());
                }
            });
            mainPane.getChildren().add(circle1);
        }
    });
```

Note that in Java 8 your code would compile just as you have it, because `circle1` is *effectively final* (meaning that it is only assigned once and is never reassigned).

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.getSource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html?is-external=true#getSource--), by this can write a common event handler for multiple cicrles without worrying which exact one was clicked:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> handler = new EventHandler<>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle( MouseEvent event )
    {
        if (event.getSource() instanceof Circle) { // to be on safe side, you may 
                                                   // remove this if-statement 
                                                   // if you are sure
            Circle c = (Circle) event.getSource();
            c.setCenterX( event.getX() );
        }
    }
};

// use it on multiple circles
circle1.setOnMouseDragged(handler);
circle2.setOnMouseDragged(handler);
...
circleN.setOnMouseDragged(handler);
```